# Template form does not render in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form that I want to display.
It looks like this:

```
# The template to be filled with the form:
# base.html
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head><title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title></head>
    <body>{% block content %}{% endblock %}</body>
</html>
```

The concrete template

```
# home.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Main{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Home page</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import home as home_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^home/$', home_view, name='home'),
]
```

This does not draw the `{{ form.as_p }}`. It only draws the submit button.
Any ideas why?

Comment: Well you don't seem to have a form in that view. Where would it be coming from?

Comment: _I have a form that I want to display_  You do?  Where is it?  This code contains no form definition at all.

Comment: I was using the same "form" for /login with the view: auth_views.login (url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),) and it was drawing a Form with user and pass. I just was tricked by this
Thanks

Comment: I used this sample on how to use login form, which is not self-explanatory for a django begginer:
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html

Answer (score 1):

Your issue stems from the fact that the template has no idea what you are referencing when you use `{{ form }}` or `{{ form.as_p }}`. The template sees no value associated with the key `'form'` in the context.

To fix this, create a `Form` object in your view and then include it in the context when you call `render`. Make sure that the key associated with the form in the context dictionary is `'form'`.